# Supply Assembly to CompilerParameters ReferencedAssemblies from memory and not disk?

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

I have a `CompilerParameters` object that I use to feed a `Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider` object and an `ICodeCompiler` object that derives from that.

Everything works OK, and I can compile code on the fly. My problem is with the referenced assemblies. Right now, I just add all assemblies from `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()` into the compiler parameter's `ReferencedAssemblies`. This works for files on the hard disk. However I have one assembly that is in memory and not on the disk. When I try to reference it, I get a `FileNotFoundException` which I expect since it is trying to add a path that doesn't exist.

So how do I pass in an actual `Assembly` object to `CompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies`?

I have seen a few posts online from 2006 and before that say it is simply not possible. I am hoping with .net 3.5 and .net 4.0 the support for this sort of thing has been added, but I am unsure.

FYI, I am using .NET 4.0

---

Also, right now I am creating a temporary file from the byte[] in program space, then loading that file into an assembly. I know the compiler does this in the background, but it also cleans up after itself I believe. It would be great if I could do:

```
CompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(Assembly a)
```

Comment: Didn't realize it was a contest, or that I even was "supposed" to mark questions as answered.

Answer (score 1):

So you have in-memory assembly that you want to add as reference?

I'm not sure that such approach is supported by `CSharpCodeProvider`.